# Reference error, says variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a function which reads from Firebase database and then creates an array of objects. I have defined variable `key`, but it is still unavailable.

```
var usersList = [];

const ref = firebase.database().ref()

function fetchUsers() {

    ref.child('users').once('value').then(snap => {
        var promises = [];

        snap.forEach(childSnap => {

            var key = childSnap.key

            promises.push
                (ref.child(`users/${key}/points`).once('value')
            );


        });

        return Promise.all(promises);

    }).then(function(snapshots) {
        return snapshots.map(snapper => {
        var points = snapper.val()
        return {uid: key, points: points};
        })
    }).then(function(usersList) {
        console.log(usersList)
    })

}
```

And this is the error I get...

```
(node:11724) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: key is not defined
```

If i just do: `key = childSnap.key`, then every object's `uid` is the same.

Comment: I strongly recommend learning, in depth, where `;` is required. (It's very simple: At the end of every statement not terminated by a block attached to the statement. So after `x = function() { };` because the block is attached to the expression, not the statement; not after `for (...) { }` because the block is attached to the statement.) Then you can make an informed choice whether to use them or to rely on the "automatic semicolon insertion" error-correction mechanism built into JavaScript. In the above, you're half-supplying them, half-relying on ASI.

Comment: Also recommend consistently preferring arrow functions over `function` functions where a `function` function isn't required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key` is only defined within the `forEach` callback. Naturally you cannot then reference it from within the second `then` callback. Moreover, which `key` would it be? For the first entry? The second? Third?

Instead, you need to return the key with the value:

```
function fetchUsers() {
    ref.child('users').once('value').then(snap => {
        var promises = [];
        snap.forEach(childSnap => {
            var key = childSnap.key;
            promises.push(
                ref.child(`users/${key}/points`).once('value').then(
                    snapper => ({key, snapper})    // **
                )
            );
        });

        return Promise.all(promises);
    }).then(function(snapshots) {
        return snapshots.map(({key, snapper}) => { // **
            var points = snapper.val();
            return {uid: key, points: points};
        });
    }).then(function(usersList) {
        console.log(usersList);
    });
}
```

On the first `**` line above, we're transforming the result from `once` so it returns an object with both the key and "snapper".

On the second `**` line, we're using destructured parameters to receive those objects as the distinct `key` and `snapper` parameters.

---

FWIW, if you want to aggressively use concise arrows:

```
function fetchUsers() {
    ref.child('users').once('value').then(snap =>
        Promise.all(snap.map(childSnap => {
            const key = childSnap.key;
            return ref.child(`users/${key}/points`)
                        .once('value')
                        .then(snapper => ({key, snapper}));
        }))
    ).then(snapshots =>
        snapshots.map(({key, snapper}) => ({uid: key, points: snapper.val()}))
    ).then(usersList => {
        console.log(usersList);
    });
}
```

Also note the use of `map` rather than declaring an array and pushing to it from a `forEach` callback. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I take your suggestions into consideration.